Macro VBS Script not running properly using Task Scheduler
I am new to scripting and task scheduler. Can someone please help me make my Task Scheduler macro automation work?
I have created a macro-VBA script to automatically open the excel file, reads the data and draft an email to be sent by schedule.
When I trigger it manually from documents folder, it is executed successfully (estimated - 5 to 10 seconds)
But when it is triggered via Task Scheduler, it says task is completed - but nothing happened. No email is sent.
The macro-VBA script and task scheduler settings are as follows:
**Filename: MacroLauncher.vbs**
'Input Excel File's Full Path
  ExcelFilePath = "C:\Users\User001\Documents\Report Extract\Latest.xlsm"

'Input Module/Macro name within the Excel File
  MacroPath = "Module1.Send_Email_Complete"

'Create an instance of Excel
  Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'Do you want this Excel instance to be visible?
  ExcelApp.Visible = False

'Prevent any App Launch Alerts (ie Update External Links)
  ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False

'Open Excel File
  Set wb = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath)

'Execute Macro Code
  ExcelApp.Run MacroPath

'Save Excel File (if applicable)
  wb.Save

'Reset Display Alerts Before Closing
  ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = True

'Close Excel File
  wb.Close

'End instance of Excel
  ExcelApp.Quit

'Clean up
Set wb = Nothing
Set ExcelApp = Nothing

'Leaves an onscreen message!
MsgBox "Your Automated Task successfully ran at " & TimeValue(Now), vbInformation

Task Scheduler Settings
General - Run only when user is logged on. Run with highest privileges
Triggers - Daily At 4:00 PM. Enabled
Actions - Start a program. C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe C:\Users\User001\Documents\Report Extract\MacroLauncher.vbs
Conditions - Wake the computer to run this task
Settings - Allow task to be run on demand
I have tried to change the following:
From:
Actions - Start a program. C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe C:\Users\User001\Documents\Report Extract\MacroLauncher.vbs
To:
Actions - Start a program. C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe C:\Users\User001\Documents\Report Extract\MacroLauncher.vbs

From:
Actions - Start a program. "C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe" "C:\Users\User001\Documents\Report Extract\MacroLauncher.vbs"
To:
Actions - Start a program. "C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe" "C:\Users\User001\Documents\Report Extract\MacroLauncher.vbs"

But still no luck.
I will really appreciate your help! :)
